# How to create json as unicode or str?

Tags: python, json, format

During tests, I got this json in json file:

```
{
  "body": "{'streamName': 'someDataTypeStreamName','datasetName': 'acdeventmappingdata','firehoseSampleTimeInterval': 180,'firehoseSampleSize': 128}"
}
```

And I got this code over my app:

```
if 'body' in event:
    event = event['body']
    if (type(event) is unicode or type(event) is str):
        event = json.loads(event) <<<<------
```

When the code is trying to run `json.loads(event)` i'm getting error: `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

I tried several string formats of the body property, but I came out with nothing.

Comment: it's pretty verbose, a valid json requires double quoted keys

Comment: I surely got it, I just don't know how to make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a JSON string, that's just the string representation of a `dict`.

```
>>> print(str({'streamName': 'someDataTypeStreamName','datasetName': 'acdeventmappingdata','firehoseSampleTimeInterval': 180,'firehoseSampleSize': 128}))
{'streamName': 'someDataTypeStreamName', 'datasetName': 'acdeventmappingdata', 'firehoseSampleTimeInterval': 180, 'firehoseSampleSize': 128}
```

vs

```
>>> print(json.dumps({'streamName': 'someDataTypeStreamName','datasetName': 'acdeventmappingdata','firehoseSampleTimeInterval': 180,'firehoseSampleSize': 128}))
{"streamName": "someDataTypeStreamName", "datasetName": "acdeventmappingdata", "firehoseSampleTimeInterval": 180, "firehoseSampleSize": 128}
```

Notice the different quotes. Confusing, I know.

Either update your code to produce valid [json](/questions/tagged/json), or parse it with [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'streamName': 'someDataTypeStreamName','datasetName': 'acdeventmappingdata','firehoseSampleTimeInterval': 180,'firehoseSampleSize': 128}")
{'streamName': 'someDataTypeStreamName', 'datasetName': 'acdeventmappingdata', 'firehoseSampleTimeInterval': 180, 'firehoseSampleSize': 128}
```

---

The file needs to look like this to work:

```
{
    "body": "{\"streamName\": \"someDataTypeStreamName\", \"datasetName\": \"acdeventmappingdata\", \"firehoseSampleTimeInterval\": 180, \"firehoseSampleSize\": 128}"
}
```

Both parts need to be valid JSON for it to work. I created it like this. Notice the double `dumps()`.

```
json.dumps({'body': json.dumps({'streamName': 'someDataTypeStreamName','datasetName': 'acdeventmappingdata','firehoseSampleTimeInterval': 180,'firehoseSampleSize': 128})}, indent=4)
```

Comment: I want that the body will remain as unicode or either as str, all the above are jsons

Comment: What you have is not valid JSON. Unless you mean the entire block is JSON, in which case you still need to do a `literal_eval()` on the `body` string after. For example `ast.literal_eval(json.loads(data)['body'])`.

Comment: The json should be unicode/str because it a test of POST request.

Comment: Where did you get the sample JSON file from? It's not going to work as is. If your app works from the browser, update the test JSON file to contain a valid JSON string in the `body` rather than what you have now.

Comment: currently it's from a file, but can also be from code

Comment: I updated my answer with a valid file that you can use. That is probably what the browser creates and sends to your app.

Comment: I made a json as a variable inside the test like this: `data = {"body": json.dumps({'streamName':........`  It fixed my problem.